# Google api search box result number

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I use google api search box. If i insert example "London Hotel" script give me a lot of result. How can i change code to give me exact number of result example 5?

Thank you for ansefer

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

```
    function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this to get all the places:

```js
places.forEach(function(place) {
```

Change that to a normal for loop, using a max of 5 or the size of the places array, whichever is smaller.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(places.length, 5); i++) {
    // and within the loop, refer to each place as 'places[i]' instead of 'place'
```